# Can Zend_File_Transfer handle two different filters of the same class?

Tags: zend-framework

## Brief question

Zend_File_Filter seems to remap added filters to their **class names** (strings) and then call them from an internal array. Is it still possible to add the same filter class with different parameters **two times** to `Zend_File_Transfer`? If yes, how?

## Explanation and test circumstances

I am using `Zend_File_Transfer` to upload images. Now I wanted to add two own filters which resize images and save them to some location (basically thumbnailing). It all works perfectly as long as I only add it one time (one thumbnail size).

But when I want to add it two times, `Zend_File_Transfer` seems to forget about the first instance and just replace it with the second one.

The code I am using looks like this:

```php
$uploadPhotoForm->getElement('photo')->addFilter('Rename', array(
    'target' => $article->getUrl() . '.' . $extension,
    'overwrite' => true
));

$uploadPhotoForm->getElement('photo')->addFilter(new Skoch_Filter_File_Resize(array(
    // no directory given means: use the default directory
    'width' => 600,
    'height' => 300,
    'keepRatio' => true,
)));

$uploadPhotoForm->getElement('photo')->addFilter(new Skoch_Filter_File_Resize(array(
    'directory' => '/default/path/thumbnail',
    'width' => 300,
    'height' => 100,
    'keepRatio' => true,
)));
```

My instances are created correctly (I debugged of construct). Yet, debugging the actual call to `filter()` leads to the following:

```php
call to Skoch_Filter_File_Resize::filter()
array(5) { [0]=> int(300) [1]=> int(100) [2]=> bool(true) 
[3]=> string(79) "/some/long/default/path/thumbnail..." [4]=> bool(true) }

call to Skoch_Filter_File_Resize::filter()
array(5) { [0]=> int(300) [1]=> int(100) [2]=> bool(true) 
[3]=> string(79) "/some/long/default/path/thumbnail..." [4]=> bool(true) }
```

So you can see that both instances are exactly the same, even though I added one instance for 600x300 and one for 300x100 pixels.

Trying to debug my instances within `Zend_File_Transfer_Abstract` I found out, that it seems to use strings for classnames within `_filter()`:

```php
foreach ($content['filters'] as $class) {
    // Comment by the author: $class is a string of my classname, checked with var_dump
    $filter = $this->_filters[$class];
        try {
            $result = $filter->filter($this->getFileName($name));

            $this->_files[$name]['destination'] = dirname($result);
            $this->_files[$name]['name']        = basename($result);
        } catch (Zend_Filter_Exception $e) {
            $this->_messages += array($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Is it really possible that `Zend_File_Transfer` cannot handle **multiple instances of the same class**? Can I somehow alias the filters, so that they are unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried building a filter chain? So that each filter is applied in sequence.
[Zend Framework Filter chains](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.filter_chains.html)